# How to call for dictionary value to enumerated list

Tags: python-3.x

```py
health_supplement_menu = [
    "Black Mamba Bulbine",
    "SA Nutrition Vaccine OCS",
    "sem10",
    "S.A.N High Strength CBD 30%",
    "Pure Shilajat Resin",
]

health_supplement_prices = {
    health_supplement_menu[0]: 18.99,
    health_supplement_menu[1]: 23.99,
    health_supplement_menu[2]: 95.00,
    health_supplement_menu[3]: 49.99,
    health_supplement_menu[4]: 25.00,
}

shopping_list = ["sem10", "Pure Shilajat Resin"]
print("Basket:\n")
for i, item in enumerate(shopping_list, 1):
    print(i, item, sep=": - ")
```

Fairly new to python.
I have a shopping menu interface, to choose an item to add to the shopping basket..

Just an example here with one menu and its dictionary values.
I have created a for loop to enumerate the shopping list,
but what I am also trying to accomplish, is to call for the values within the dictionary to print beside the items that are witin the shopping list to show the price.

Comment: After fixing the couple of typos, you can try `print(i, item, health_supplement_prices[item], sep=": - ")`

Comment: If I wanted to call other menu prices, would I also factor it in where health_supplement_prices are, all separated by a comma?
Or would I have to create an overall dictionary with all the prices to call from..
If you could just point me in the right direction..
That solution worked out perfectly thank you

Comment: to add items to the basket, you would add to the list `shopping_list`